# Get hex values between a range in c#

Tags: c#, hex

Please assist.  How do i get the list of hex addresses between a specific range.

0x000000 > 0x0001B3

Need to do something like

`for(int i=0;i< 10;i++)
{
 //do stuff here
}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: From your example looks like you just want to translate the hex to decimal.. so please explain better what you mean by "hex addresses".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0x0; i <= 0x1b3; i++) {
    // Do stuff with i

    // Converts the integer to hex, if that's what you wanted.
    string str = i.ToString("X");
}
```